# Error in SQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have 2 tables, `Portfolio` and `Transactions`. When you insert `Transaction_Amount` value into the Transactions, the Portfolio should be updated too. Below is the table structure.

[image]

I created a Trigger so whenever I insert a value into the `Transactions`, the `Portfolio` will be updated too.

Below is my MYSQL Trigger

```
USE `custom_sample`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Transactions_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `Transactions` FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Portfolio 
SET Invest_Amount = Invest_Amount+Transactions.Transaction_Amount
where
Portfolio.idPortfolio = Transactions.idPortfolio
```

However this didn't work. It says `Unknown column Transactions.idPortfolio in where clause`

What is wrong with my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The record of the triggered table can be referenced by `NEW` (or `OLD` for the values before in case of an update) instead of the table name.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Transactions_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `Transactions` 
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE Portfolio 
    SET Invest_Amount = Invest_Amount + NEW.Transaction_Amount
    WHERE idPortfolio = NEW.idPortfolio
```